# Downloading a large file using Node.js should have less time complexity

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I want to develop a high performing file downloader using node.js . I may have to download files upto 10GB. I have tried using in built node modules .Below is the code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('download.bin');

var contentLength;
var length;
var responseData = '';
var timeDiff = 0;
var fileurl = 'http://speed.hetzner.de/1GB.bin';
var request = http.get(fileurl, function (response) {
    timeDiff = new Date().getTime();
    contentLength = parseInt(response.headers['content-length']); // in bytes
    length = [];

    // Grab the data buffer of the request
    response.on('data', (d) => {
        responseData += d;
        length.push(d.length);
        let sum = length.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        let completedParcentage = (sum / contentLength) * 100;
        console.log(`completed reading ${sum} bytes out of ${contentLength} bytes`);
        console.log(`${completedParcentage} percentage of download complete`);
        if (completedParcentage == 100) {
            console.log(new Date().getTime() - timeDiff, 'check-this-now');

        }

    });

    response.on('end', () => {
        file.write(responseData);
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - timeDiff, 'check-this-now');
    });

});
```

I am downloading a 1 GB file from an API. I takes 115 seconds to complete. But I get error :

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - **JavaScript heap out of memory**
1: node::Abort() [node]
2: 0x557f33ccc011 [node]
3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)
```

After going through the documentation I got to know that we need to specify some flag to increase heap size.

But is there any efficient way to implement this without using any flags with built in modules ?

If there is no way , could you suggest any module or any architecture like serving using NGINX or something ?

Note: I have also used request, request-progress module, it works good but i want to know other solutions also.

Comment: I'm not a node expert, but can't you pipe the input/reading stream of the response to the output/writing stream of your file? If you wait for the end of the HTTP response, then read the body and write it all in the file at once, you load the whole file in memory and that's your problem. You must write it chunk by chunk with a buffer, or using streams, which probably would be the best since it would be handled by node. Some good reading: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is this:

```
responseData += d;
```

You are saving the file to RAM. Regardless of how large you configure node's heap this means you will need at minimum 10GB of RAM to buffer the file (I admit that I don't know your hardware and you may have a machine with 12GB or 16GB of RAM. but machines available to me are maxed out at 8GB). But the worst part is if your requirements ever change and you need to download a 20GB file you will need to upgrade your hardware to have 20GB of RAM (or configure your virtual memory). On top of it I'm not even sure if node can be configured with 10GB heap.

Instead use your hard disk to buffer the downloaded data:

```
response.on('data', (d) => {
    file.write(d); // THIS FIXES EVERYTHING
    let sum += d.length;
    let completedParcentage = (sum / contentLength) * 100;
    console.log(`completed reading ${sum} bytes out of ${contentLength} bytes`);
    console.log(`${completedParcentage} percentage of download complete`);
    if (completedParcentage == 100) {
        console.log(new Date().getTime() - timeDiff, 'check-this-now');

    }

});
```

#### Additional answer

If you don't want to accidentally partially download a file (if the download is incomplete) then you can do what browsers do and store it to a temporary file first before renaming the file when the download is complete:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('download.temp');

// then later

response.on('end', () => {
    file.end(()=>{
        // finish closing file
        fs.rename('download.temp', 'download.bin', () => {
            // finish renaming file
            console.log(new Date().getTime() - timeDiff, 'check-this-now');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer..but this approach takes nearly 15 minutes to download 1 GB file. I am looking for a high performing solution. Is there any better way to increase the speed of writes ?

Comment: @unnamed-bull I doubt that the disk write is the cause or the 15 minute download. This approach has almost zero delays compared to your original approach. Look at upgrading your network connections. 1GB file in 15 minutes implies you have a 10Mbps network bottleneck